# "@" meaning in permission of file?

Tags: terminal, permissions, chmod

I ran `ls -la` on mac terminal and i got below output :

```
rwxr-xr-x  4 user  staff   136 Oct  2 18:55 .
drwxr-xr-x  6 user  staff   204 Aug 23 11:39 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff  2622 Oct  2 18:03 File2.php
-rw-r--r--@ 1 user  staff   392 Oct  2 19:14 File1.php
 #        ^
 #        this one here
```

If you see the permission for `File1.php`, there is an `@` at the end.What is the significance / meaning of this `@` sign here? 
If it is of any worth, file1 is created through dreamweaver application.

Not sure what *keyword* to use to google it, tried some, found nothing so come to last resort! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is an @ in the permissions fields, the file or directory has extended attributes. According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xattr.1.html) extended attributes are arbitrary metadata stored with a file, but separate from the filesystem attributes (such as modification time or file size).  The metadata is often a null-terminated UTF-8 string, but can also be arbitrary binary data. You can run `ls -@l` to list them

Answer (score 1):

This question has already been answered here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10/what-does-the-mean-in-ls-l

The "@" denotes additional file attributes that can be associated with metadata.